# Issue trying to use multiple refs for an array of items

Tags: reactjs, arrays, react-hooks

I am currently trying to add a list of projects to a web page and have it that when a user hovers over the image of a Project, a tooltip will appear to to the left of the project with all the project details. I am using the PopperJS library to generate the tooltip. I managed to get this working for one project using useRef but i am unable to make it work for an array of projects. I am trying to use multiple useRefs with different names for each project but i didn't think that was the best way and i am receiving the following error that i am not sure how to fix with below setup:

*Function components cannot have string refs*

Any help on how to fix this would be greatly appreciated! Thank you

The code for the iteration over the array is:

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from "react";
import Card from "./UI/Card";
import ToolTip from "./UI/Tooltip";
import ProjectData from "./data/Projects.json";

const Projects = (props) => {
  const MidpointRef = useRef();
  const SpacesRef = useRef();
  const MovieMinderRef = useRef();
  const midpointTooltipRef = useRef();
  const spacesTooltipRef = useRef();
  const MovieMinderTooltipRef = useRef();
  const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggleToolTip = () => {
    setIsOpen(!isOpen);
  };

  return ProjectData.map((project) => {
    return (
      <Card>
        <div
          key={project.id}
          className={`flex project-thumbnail ${project.Name}`}
          onMouseEnter={toggleToolTip}
          onMouseLeave={toggleToolTip}
          boxRef={`${project.Name}Ref`}
        >
          <button
            class="view-button"
            onMouseEnter={props.onMouseEnter}
            onMouseLeave={props.onMouseLeave}
          >
            Click to view
          </button>
        </div>
        <ToolTip
          ref={`${project.Name}TooltipRef`}
          toolTipState={isOpen}
          boxRef={`${project.Name}Ref`}
        />
      </Card>
    );
  });
```

The OnMouseEnter/OnMouseLeave are handlers that make the cursor smaller.

The Tooltip component code is:

```
import classNames from "classnames";
import { useRef, forwardRef } from "react";
import { usePopper } from "react-popper";

const ToolTip = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const { attributes } = usePopper(
    props.boxRef.current,
    ref.current,
    {}
  );
  return (
    <div
      id="tooltip"
      role="tooltip"
      className={classNames("tooltip", {
        "tooltip-active": props.toolTipState,
      })}
      ref={ref}
      {...attributes.popper}
    >
      My tooltip
    </div>
  );
});

export default ToolTip;
```

Comment: ``${project.Name}TooltipRef`` doesn't work like you think it does. It's just a string, and doesn't point to the actual ref. You can either lose the `map`, or use one ref whose value is an array.

Comment: Thank you @nullptr, appreciate you taking the time. I have got it working now.